# Tor-dimension of $A/(a)\otimes_k B$, where $A$ and $B$ are Dedekind domains

Tags: homological-algebra, krull-dimension, dedekind-domain, global-dimension

Let $A$ and $B$ be two Dedekind domains which contain a field $k$ which is algebraically closed in both $A$ and $B$. Let $a$ be a non zero element in $A$.

What is the Tor-dimension of $A\otimes_k B$? And of $A/(a)\otimes_k B$?

Comment: What have you tried? I figure this type of stuff is in Weibel's chapter on global dimensions.

Comment: I presume that $A\otimes B$ is regular, hence its Tor dimension coincides with its Krull dimension which should be $2$. For $A/(a)\otimes B$ I am more confused. I would have hope it is one, but it is not reduced so I do not know…

Comment: Said differently, given a (Noetherian commutative) ring $R$, for which element $r\in R$ does the dimension of $R/(r)$ is strictly smaller than that of $R$?